# change row background color based on column value in classic report in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

Is there a way to programmatically set the background color of a row based on data on column (exp . mgr =100 the row  color 
 green other that blue  ....ex ). Is there a method (javascript?) by which this can be achieved? Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of page inline CSS and "execute when page loads" Javascript like this:

### Page inline CSS

```
#myreport td {background-color: #aaccff}
```

### "Execute when page loads" Javascript

```
$('#myreport td[headers="MGR"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === '100'
}).parent().children().css('background-color', '#aaffaa');
```

Here `myreport` is the static ID you assigned to the report region.

---

Another way without Javascript would be to build a bespoke report template with conditional column templates where one has the PL/SQL condition:

```
'#MGR#' = '100'
```

Comment: thanks dear , but this not working fine on IR report , i tried create a new template but how i can choose the template ,i can't find it .

Comment: No, @jaw, this only works in a classic report, which is what your question asked for.  In an Interactive Report you can do it at runtime via the Actions menu (Format -> Highlight).

Comment: @Tony, is there a way to hide presets from end user? not sure if I explained clearly what I meant but I'm talking about the collapsible tags when you set a highlight.

Comment: @Oguen Sorry I don't understand the question.  Maybe raise a new question with a screenshot?